# NSFileManager Attributesforitem fails and returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems, nsfilemanager, filepicker.io

Right now I am working on an iOS app that needs `NSFileManager` but when I do the `attributesOfItemAtPath:` method, it returns null. This also fails on NSData and the `dataWithContentsOfFile:` method. I do not understand why this is happening. The file URL that I am using looks something like this :`file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/597DE145-33D7-4F92-AE95-029D5CF15291/tmp/Kv7DWqtRWH7WnN47HdDW`.I suspect it might be something to do with the URL, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the `NSURL` to a path for use with any of the `NSFileManager` methods that take a string. Do this by calling the `path` method on the URL.

```
NSURL *someURL = ... // some file URL
NSString *path = [someURL path]; // convert the file:// URL to a file path
NSDictionary *info = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path];
```

Comment: I'm there with you :)